# Compiling Braintree dependency in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, braintree

I am brand new to Android Studio. I imported my project from Eclipse to Android Studio just fine, but I'm having some trouble trying to add a couple of dependencies from Braintree SDK.

I'm trying to add the below dependencies.

compile 'com.braintreepayments:encryption:2.+'
compile 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:1.+'

When I try to build my project, it says,

Failed to find: com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:1.+
Failed to find: com.braintreepayments.api:encryption:2.+

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks,

M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found the answer.

I need to add this

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

in the build.gradel of my app.